# Mailchimp Confirmation page on same window/tab

Tags: javascript, mailchimp

I've created a super simple mailchimp form for a website (just email). http://jelato.love/newsletter

When clicking on subscribe it opens a new window with a custom URL I created with a "thank you" message that redirects to the home of the site after 2 seconds.

Anyone knows if there is any way to avoid that new window? Click on subscribe and load on same window/tab that custom URL?

Thank you so much

Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup {background: transparent!important; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;color: #cd4038!important;}
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup" class="element">
<form action="https://love.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=934cacc38490d44fbae4b28e4&amp;id=74bd78df58" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email adress" required>

<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_934cacc38490d44fbae4b28e4_74bd78df58" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `target` attribute or use `target="_self"`

Using `target="_blank"` open a new tab when you submit the form.

```
<form action="https://love.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=934cacc38490d44fbae4b28e4&amp;id=74bd78df58" 
method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate"
target="" novalidate>
```

**Target** **attributes** from [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp)

> _blank The response is displayed in a new window or tab
>
> _self :    The response is displayed in the same frame (this is default)
>
> _parent :  The response is displayed in the parent frame
>
> _top : The response is displayed in the full body of the window
>
> framename :    The response is displayed in a named iframe

Your code updated:

```
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup {background: transparent!important; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;color: #cd4038!important;}
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup" class="element">
<form action="https://love.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=934cacc38490d44fbae4b28e4&amp;id=74bd78df58" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="" novalidate>
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email adress" required>

<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_934cacc38490d44fbae4b28e4_74bd78df58" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works perfectly. Feeling a bit dumb I didn't see that target attribute. :)